# Why for loop does not execute inside TmerTask

Tags: java, android

I want to repeat a `for loop` inside below code inside a service every some time ,but it print only one line and runs one time only

```
  public void startTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    initializeTimerTask();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 10000);

}
   public void initializeTimerTask() {
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
                Log.i("TAG", "  inside method ");}

        }


    };
}
```

Comment: Works for me, BTW `timer.schedule(timerTask, 10000);` is 10 seconds

Comment: Provide *full* [mcve]. BTW you are setting 10 seconds *delay* before execution.

Comment: Work for me after 10 seconds delay.

Comment: after 10 seconds it prints only one line not 10 lines

Comment: It print 10 lines. You may provide more about your problem. Maybe other part affect its result.

Comment: It's inside a service

Comment: Maybe your task is interrupted after the first execution. Why you don't debug this line and check if it's called multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the following method.

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)
```

So the task executes only once after delay.
If you want to execute it periodically you need to call the bellow method.(you may pass same value for delay and period)

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

Your another query is it prints first line only. Most probably this is an issue with the Log. try `System.out.print()` instead of `Log.i()` to debug.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private int counter = 1;

    public void run() {
        timerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(this, "" + counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                counter++;
            }
        });
        if (counter == 10) {
            myTimer.cancel();
            myTimer.purge();

        }

    }
}
```

//Thats the usage like on ButtonClick

```
                MyTimerTask myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
                Timer myTimer = new Timer();
                myTimer.schedule(myTimerTask, 500, 1000);
```

Do you really need to run Loop ?